# Why does my overlay normal distribution curve looks strange?

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

I want to overlay a normal distribution curve. But it looks strange. Is this correct way of doing it?

```
g <- dataset$NEW_CASE_FATALITY_RATE

h <- hist(g # depandant variable (case_fatality_rate)
, main = "Histogram - Case Fatality Rate Frequency" # chart title
, xlab = "Case Fatality Rate",
ylab = "Frequency",
col = "#f0ffff",
breaks = 15,
freq = FALSE,
prob = TRUE,
xlim = c(0.5,2.5),
ylim = c(0.0,2.0)
)



xfit <- seq(min(g), max(g), length = 5) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(g), sd = sd(g)) 
yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(g) 

lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2)

grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL,
     lty = 1, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are overlaying your density line on a frequency plot instead of a density (probability) plot. Add  `probability = TRUE` to your `hist()` call and it should solve the problem.

**Edit**:

As suggested by @Ben Bolker in the comments, increasing the xfit will also help. Ideally you'll have as many points as the length of your `g` variable or more to create a density line.

I have taken out the line where you adjust yfit, as well as some parameters in your hist call:

```r
h <- hist(g, # depandant variable (case_fatality_rate)
          probability=TRUE,
          main = "Histogram - Case Fatality Rate Frequency", # chart title
          xlab = "Case Fatality Rate",
          ylab = "Frequency",
          col = "#f0ffff",
          breaks = 15,
          xlim = c(0.5,2.5),
          ylim = c(0.0,2.0)
)

xfit <- seq(min(g), max(g), length = length(g)) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(g), sd = sd(g)) 

lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2)

#compare to the default density line
lines(density(g), col='red')
```

Ultimately, overlaying a theoretical distribution on real data can look weird. This can be the case if you have few data points, since you use the mean and standard deviation of your *sample data* to plot your normal distribution.

The code above is correct, it might just not be the best way to present your sample data from a practical statistics point of view.

Comment: I would also recommend `length = 51` (or maybe 11, but definitely > 5)  when defining `xfit`

Comment: I did that it says Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) :
  "prob" is not a graphical parameter
2: In title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  "prob" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(1, ...) : "prob" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(2, ...) : "prob" is not a graphical parameter